# How can I change the fontsize of a GridviewColumnHeader?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, header, gridviewcolumn

I included everything below since it's not that much. I wasn't sure if something I put elsewhere was causing my setter to not work properly.

```
                <ListView x:Name="lvReports"
                             SelectionMode="Single"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding reportsCollection}" Height="432" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="30pt"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="800"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <DockPanel Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                            <Image Source="\Images\ProductivityByEmployeesReport.png"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18pt" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="colName" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}" Header="Reports">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DockPanel>
                                            <Rectangle Width="18"/>
                                            <CheckBox>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding displayName}"/>
                                            </CheckBox>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember something like this but I forgot exactly how I fixed it.  I think I had to put the HeaderStyle in a GridViewColumnHeader block (not directly in GridViewColumn).

Comment: I copied your code to try and fix and your code as is worked for me.  I did not copy your GroupStyle so there may be a conflict there.

Comment: yah, it looked like it should have worked, but the damned thing never changed size.

Comment: I should have posted my comment as and answer and I would have gotten credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `<ListView.Resources>`

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" x:Key="ColumnHeaderLarge">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
</Style>
```

To set Fontsize to 14, use the style as:

```
<GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderLarge}">
```

Comment: I musta done something stupid cuz my code is workign fine now. Your answer does fit the question, though so I'm giving you the nod.

Comment: Well even I went ahead with the question title & assumed you were actually looking for a way to change font size, with a glance on the code. Sorry for the no help...